# Best way to bookmark items on Pinboard.in

Tags: bookmarks

I recently changed over from using Delicious to http://Pinboard.in. What's the best way to bookmark a page to Pinboard from my Android phone?

Comment: Just a note for those who aren't familiar with Pinboard.in, it's basically a slimmed down version of delicious.com, done right.  It's really worth the $8.53 signup fee for the functionality and ease of use.

Answer (score 8):

Here are 4 free options...

**1) The [PinDroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/pindroid/com.pindroid) app:**

It's a port from [DeliciousDroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/deliciousdroid/com.deliciousdroid) and was just added to the market yesterday.  It looks pretty sweet.  Here's some [screenshots](http://code.google.com/p/pindroid/wiki/Screenshots).

**2) Save the Pinboard.in bookmarklet as a bookmark:** (this is still my favorite option)

```
javascript:q=location.href;if(document.getSelection){d=document.getSelection();}else{d='';};p=document.title;void(open('http://pinboard.in/add?url='+encodeURIComponent(q)+'&description='+encodeURIComponent(d)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(p),'Pinboard', 'toolbar=no,width=700,height=350'));
```

This works particularly well in Dolphin Browser HD (but it'll also work in other browswers).  Just create new bookmark, name it Pinboard Share and paste the above text in as the location.  When you are on a site you want to save, slide open the bookmarks toolbar and click your Pinboard Share and it'll bring up the popup share window with the URL and Title already filled in.  Personally, I like saving it as a gesture in Dolphin to make it even easier.

If you don't want to have to enter anything in, here's the code for the "Read Later" pinboard bookmarklet that'll just save the url automatically to your "Read Later" list without prompting you to enter tags, or a description.  I find this easy to do in a hurry then go back an organize later on my PC:

```
javascript:q=location.href;p=document.title;void(t=open('http://pinboard.in/add?later=yes&noui=yes&jump=close&url='+encodeURIComponent(q)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(p),'Pinboard','toolbar=no,width=100,height=100'));t.blur();
```

**3) Download [Bookmarklet Free](http://www.appbrain.com/app/bookmarklet-free/com.kurtchen.android.bookmarklet.free)**

Go to "Custom Services" and add your own.  Name it Pinboard or whatever you want.  In the "Base URL" field enter `http://pinboard.in/add?` then in the "Title Parameter" field enter `title` and in the "URL Parameter" field enter `url`.  Now when you choose to "Share" from your browser, you'll have all the regular options like Email, Twitter and any of the options you chose in Bookmarklet Free, including your new Pinboard bookmarklet. *(note: it actually took a little while for the name to take for me, it was listed as "My Service" for a while in my Share menu.)*

**4) [Post by Email](http://pinboard.in/howto/#post_by_mail)**

With your formatted Pinboard email you can choose the share option on any page and email to to our pinboard account.  The instructions to do this are on the Pinboard how-to section.  I prefer the first option I shared but this is a decent last resort.

Comment: +1 for PinDroid. I use it daily and contact the developer regularly via Google Code issues and Twitter - great contact!

Comment: In Chrome Bookmarklets only seem to work from the search bar, not the bookmarks menu

Answer (score 3):

[Save to Pinboard](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/save-to-pinboard_kafl.html).